# Highlight text diff on client?

Tags: javascript, diff

I want to compare 2 text values on a web page and highlight the differences. Can I do this client-side, preferably with jQuery or Prototype?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This diff-patch-match library appears to do a really good job:

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

The project has JavaScript, C#, C++, Python, and Java implementations that all do the same thing.

Comment: I went through this and ended up creating a wrapper library to help with the "presentation work" needed to use `diff_match_patch`: https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff

Comment: @arnab You are a beautiful person. Love the the jsfiddle you link to from your GitHub project page.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the the [wikEd diff library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/diff) and the [online tool and demo](http://cacycle.altervista.org/wikEd-diff-tool.html).

The library creates inline text comparisons with block move highlighting and is character/word-based. It has been optimized for Wikipedia, but works equally well for other text types and program code. The library code is customizable, has Unicode support, is extensively commented, and is free (PD).